# Unable to trigger Ajax code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using sweatalert UI as my prompt out message for confirmation. Inside my jQuery I had an Ajax code to remove the item when user click on "Yes,Delete It".

But I'm not sure why my Ajax code unable to trigger. Is there any code that I put wrongly? Please point it out for me. Thanks

Here are my html code for the button:

```
<form id="packageRemove" class="packageRemove" name="packageRemove">
    <input type="hidden" id="pRemove" name="pRemove" class="pRemove" value="1">
        <button style="left:-35px;" class="btn btn-primary pull-right warning-message-parameter">X</button>
</form>
```

Here are my ui-notification.js code that i used to trigger the ajax code:

```
$(".warning-message-parameter").on("click", function(e) {
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this directory file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            }, function(isConfirm) {
                if(isConfirm) {
                    $.ajax({
                            url: 'packageDelete.php',
                            data: el.closest('packageRemove').serialize(),
                            type: 'post',   
                            success: function(){
                                swal("Deleted!", "Your directory file has been deleted.", "success");
                            }
                    });
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelled", "Your directory file is safe :)", "error");
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: did you check console?

Comment: i getting this error
ReferenceError: el is not defined

Comment: Yes, you haven't defined el variable in your code anywhere. Try $(this).closest().. and don't forget to bind $(this) in your function...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **el** is not defined because you named the variable **e** :

```
("click", function(e) {
```

Change to

```
("click", function(el) {
```

Comment: i change to data: $(this).closest('packageRemove').serialize(),

but the data return is empty, may i know why?

Comment: Care of closure, $(this) can refer to something else in this place.